# How do I use jQuery.Deferred with a plain function?

Tags: function, arguments, promise, sample, jquery-deferred

The [Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) documentation says it can take an optional function argument, but there is not an example. How do I use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a syntactic sugar, through which you can add a callback/handler on resolve or reject on the same deferred object.

so, the following two code pieces will do the same thing.

```
// with constructor method argument
var x = $.Deferred(function(selfDfd){ 
           selfDfd.done( console.log.bind(console,'I am resolved,in constructor')); 
        });
x.resolve();

// without constructor method argument

var y = $.Deferred();
y.done(console.log.bind(console,'I am resolved, NO constructor args'))
y.resolve();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```js
      function foo(){ console.log("Yes!!!")}
      function bar(){ console.log("Are we there yet?")}
      function baz(){ console.log("I can't hold it much longer!?")}

      with($.Deferred() )
        {
        done(foo);
        bar();
        baz();
        resolve(foo);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

A generator would have the same effect:

```js
      var foobarbaz = function(i){var count = count || i; return function(){console.log("Yes!!!"); return ++count;}}
      var bar = function(){ console.log("Are we there yet?")}
      var baz = function(){ console.log("I can't hold it much longer!?")}

      
      var done = foobarbaz(0);
      bar();
      baz();
      done();
```

**References**

- [JavaScript FAQ: Notes - Closures](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/)
- [Functional JavaScript: Capturing Variables for Great Good](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/functional-javascript/9781449360757/ch04.html#id923116)
- [MDN: Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators)
- [Asynchronous programming and continuation-passing style in JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2012/06/continuation-passing-style.html)